# Display items in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have 2 `JList` components. When I click on an item from `JList A`, `JList B` will get populated.

Both, `JList` will have the same set of records displayed. (But, if we click on an item in `JList A`, that item Should not get displayed in `JList B`). How can I do this?

My workings:

```
listA.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting()==false) {             
            listB.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
                public int getSize() {
                    return allAnimals("Lions").size();
                }
                public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                    return allAnimals("Lions").keySet().toArray()[index];
                }
        });
```

But, I am unable to remove the item clicked in `JLIst A` from `JList B`. How can I make this possible?

According to the above code, When i click on `JList A`, all the items get's displayed in `JList B`. I need to display all the items except the one selected on `JList A`. How can I do this?

Signature of `allAnimals()` method;

```
public Map<String, Animal> allAnimals(String animalName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I understood is you just want to update content in a JList. The way I've done it before is by creating a DefaultListModel and assign it to the JList.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listModel);
```

From there, you can either add or delete elements from the listmodel and the JList will automatically update.

```
//add new element to the listmodel
listModel.add(/*index*/ 0, /*random object content*/ "Lions");

//remove specific element
listModel.remove(0);

//remove specific object
listModel.removeElement(someObject);

//remove all elements
listModel.removeAllElements();
```

I hope that answered your question.